# Typescript VS2017 stops at first line, error: Debugger agent is not enabled

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, typescript, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

When I start a newly created Typescript Project in Visual Studio 2017 theres some strange behaviour going on.

-The debugger breaks on the very first line

-The output shows:

```
code:-32000
message:Debugger agent is not enabled
```

-Many scripts in solution explorer (see screenshot)

-Node output:

```
Debugger listening on wb://127.0.0.1:5858/03dde2a0-7ae8-44fc-8b29-53b99c072de7
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
```

Screenshot:
[image: vs screenshot]

## Edit:

Seems to be a problem with the new node version. If I switch back to 5.4.1.0 (included in VS2017) everything works fine. I read that there has been a change in debugger protocol maybe it has something to do with that... gotta wait for an update.

Comment: So this issue has been resolved, am I right?

Comment: Kind of, I want to use the current version < 8 but thats a different problem then. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working again by using the included node version of VS2017. There seems to be a problem with the new version <8.

You can choose which version to use by putting the path to the exe folder on top of the list here: `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management > External Web Tools`

Answer (score 0):

To show the Console, we can use: Debug -> Windows -> JavaScript Console.

Michael Braude showed two suggestions for the similar issue:

> 1.Use JavaScript Console of Visual Studio. Frankly, this way is OK for me when I am developing on PC with two displays (I runs emulator on
>   one screen and debug with Visual Studio on another), but a bit
>   uncomfortable when I am developing on Notebook with one screen.
>
> 2.Run a solution without debugging (CTRL+F5), in this case VS's debugger isn't attached to browser. This looks as simple solution, but
>   you need to be aware that in this case breakpoints don't stop run-time
>   and you have to use debugger; keyword.

For detailed information:

[Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova stops work correct after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750376/visual-studio-tools-for-apache-cordova-stops-work-correct-after-update)